# Joomla 3 with K2 - Category description and image needs to be shown

Tags: categories, joomla3.0, k2

I have site at v-Boge.org - all articles are K2. Found quite a wierd thing: When I make one menu k2-category, that menu item will show me category image and description and under it articles of that category. But when I create exactly the same menu for another category - it won't give me the category image and description. I've checked all settings to be the same both for both menus and for both categories. Even compared sql lines for both menus and categoris - can't trace what makes the difference! Anybody could advise?

PS I even rebuilt the whole site from scratch thinking it might be because the site is old and accumulated bugs - to no avail... Really need a helping hand... People say it won't work, K2 doesn't show category description. But the point is - that for one category it does work. So it has to work for the rest of 'em!

Comment: Well K2 can show the category description. Otherwise, your issue can have many causes do you have a live link to debug?

Comment: @web-tiki, sorry just seen your responce. The issue is not solved and needs to be. Are you still willing to help out?

Comment: I would suggest you delete this question and ask a new one on http://joomla.stackexchange.com/ more people would be able to help on that stack exchange site.